# How do you display a js map in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, map

I have a customer apex controller that products a payload with an json apex map of map<String, List>. once i execute the apex method the javascript i convert it with json.parse and load them on to a new js map using New Map([]). as far as i am aware the map is not empty as the console logs show that the map has values, but on the lwc page it doesnt show any txt as i used the code below

```
<template for:each={responseMap} for:item="mapItem">
{mapItem.key}
<template for:each={mapItem.value} for:item="innermap">
<li key={innermap.id}>{innermap.Name}</li>
</template>
</template>
```

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2):

You cannot display map in LWC HTML.

> To render a list of items, use **for:each** directive or the iterator directive to iterate over an **array**. ~ https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-lists.html

1. Convert Map to List.

```js
this.data = Object.entries(responseMap).map(([key, value]) => ({
   key,
   value
});
```

2. Use List in HTML

```html
<template>
   <template for:each={data} for:item="mapItem">
      {mapItem.key}
      <template for:each={mapItem.value} for:item="innermap">
         <li key={innermap.id}>{innermap.Name}</li>
      </template>
   </template>
</template>
```

Comment: i tried doing this with both the response map, parsed map, and the newly created map and i would always see the map empty in the console logs, could you give some more detail in regards to this, thank you